# How to cite from a .ris file

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a Latex code

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
 \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}                           
 \addbibresource[datatype=ris]{test.ris}
 \begin{document}
 \cite{ref_test}
 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

and a .ris document

```
TY  - JOUR
ID  - ref_test
AU  - author1
AU  - author2
TI  - Big title
JA  - The Great Journal
PY  - 2012/07/15/online
VL  - 3
PB  - The Grand Publishing Group.
SN  - 146-157
ER  -
```

I attempt to use the

```
ID
```

field to create a reference. However running

```
xelatex citation.tex
```

I get the following error

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'ref_test' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 7.
```

I shouldn't run

```
bibtex citation_test.aux
```

because the backend is specified as biber.

Running

```
biber citation_test
```

gives the following error

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.6
INFO - Logfile is 'citation_test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'citation_test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
ERROR - Error loading data source package 'Biber::Input::file::ris': Can't locate Biber/Input/file/ris.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Biber::Input::file::ris module) (@INC contains: /tmp/par-76/cache-cd1af140044333e1ef20f6247fed92316f8757f1/inc/lib /tmp/par-76/cache-cd1af140044333e1ef20f6247fed92316f8757f1/inc CODE(0x31099d8) CODE(0x3118e88)) at (eval 142) line 2.

INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

How cite from a .ris file?

Comment: You should run `biber` since you specify `backend=biber`.

Comment: Exactly how to run biber?

Comment: Same as you would `bibtex`: `biber citation_test`.

Comment: running biber citation_test.aux
gives

Comment: INFO - This is Biber 2.6
INFO - Logfile is 'citation_test.aux.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'citation_test.aux.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: Now that I didn't say `biber citation_test.aux`, just `biber citation_test`.

Comment: Running biber citation_test
gives

Comment: INFO - This is Biber 2.6
INFO - Logfile is 'citation_test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'citation_test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
ERROR - Error loading data source package 'Biber::Input::file::ris': Can't locate Biber/Input/file/ris.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Biber::Input::file::ris module) (@INC contains: /tmp/par-76/cache-cd1af140044333e1ef20f6247fed92316f8757f1/inc/lib /tmp/par-76/cache-cd1af140044333e1ef20f6247fed92316f8757f1/inc CODE(0x26287a8) CODE(0x2637d28)) at (eval 142) line 2.

INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: You can't use `ris` as the `datatype`. The only supported types are `bibtex` and `biblatexml`.

Comment: One can use the online converter:  https://www.bruot.org/ris2bib/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ris` is not a currently supported data type according to the manual. The two supported types are `bibtex` and `biblatexml`. See page 77 of the current manual.

I convert `ris` to `xml` using `ris2xml` and then convert the result to `bibtex` using `xml2bib`. For example,

```bash
ris2xml "<filename>.ris" | xml2bib -b > "<filename>.bib"
```

where `<filename>` is the base file name. These instructions assume a Unix-ish system, obviously, but there may be something similar for other platforms.

Comment: So you mean a raw .ris file is not suitable for Latex?

Comment: @Viesturs It is not a question of whether it is suitable for LaTeX. A `.bib` is unsuitable for LaTeX, too. The point is it is unsuitable for Biblatex/Biber.

Comment: In past versions of Biber there was a rudimentary experimental support for RIS files. But that was dropped, because people didn't really seem to use it and it was getting increasingly hard to make the RIS branch of code keep up with the `.bib` and `biblatexml` branches.

Comment: @moewe Interesting. I didn't know that - I've been using this workflow for ages. On the other hand, I don't use the RIS file directly, even when converted, but add the entries to the relevant BIB file.

Comment: Or one can use the online converter:  https://www.bruot.org/ris2bib/

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `BibItNow` extension on Google Chrome to generate `Bibtex`, `RIS`, `Endnote`, `APA`, `MLA` bibliography items from journal articles, books and etc:
You can learn more in [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bibitnow/bmnfikjlonhkoojjfddnlbinkkapmldg).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! And thanks for providing an answer! Can you make it more self-contained?
Links tend to disappear or become invalid.
You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Mendeley. Drag the .ris citation into your documents, then copy as a bibtex entry. Fastest option I've found since https://www.bruot.org/ris2bib/ is no longer active.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the online converter from ris to bibtex.
https://www.bruot.org/ris2bib/